# Login Script not Working (Python, Selenium+PhantomJs)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, phantomjs

Hey so I'm attempting to sign in on twitter via selenium but my script only fills in the username form and nothing else. I've tried finding the elements via xpath but still nothing. No errors/exceptions raised either so I'm pretty clueless, here's the code:

```
def login():
    """login script"""
    service_args = [
        '--proxy=52.183.30.241:8888',
        '--proxy-type=http',
        '--ignore-ssl-errors=true'
        ]
    execpath = r'C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe'
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=service_args, executable_path=execpath)
    driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
    driver.get('https:twitter.com/login')
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-username-field')
    elem.send_keys('username')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-password-field')
    elem.send_keys('password')
    elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.submit.btn.primary-btn').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.save_screenshot('C:\\Users\\Ben\\Pictures\\screen.png')
```

Here's the screenshot it gives me.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you entered the correct password and username ?, it works for me

Comment: Yes, and when I remove the log in button click command, it gives me the same thing... Really weird